# Unable to Pass Variable from controller to service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass a zip code to a service that runs an API call using this zip. The problem is, every time I enter a zip and search, the zip code is not passed to the service properly and my HTTP request sends with the zip code as undefined.

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('MainCtrl', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'Reps', function($scope, Reps) {
  $scope.search = function() {
    Reps.search($scope.zipCode)
      .success(function(response) {
        console.log('Success ' + response);
      })
      .failure(function(response) {
        console.log('Failure ' + response);
      })
  }
}]);
```

My service:

```
angular.module('MainService', []).factory('Reps', ['$http', function($http) {
  var root = 'https://www.api.com/locate?';
  var apiKey = '&apikey=foo';
  var fields = '&fields=bar';

  return {
    search: function(zipCode) {
      var query = root + zipCode + apiKey + fields;
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: query
      })
    }
  }
}])
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="searchForRep">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchForRep" ng-model="zipCode" placeholder="Zip Code (11216)">
  </div>
  <button ui-sref="reps" ng-click="search()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, as mentioned, the zip code does not seem to pass to my service correctly, which is causing the HTTP request to send as:

```
https://www.api.com/locate?undefined&apikey=foo&fields=bar
```

Any idea what the issue is with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code it should work. It is working on my plunker, except you did not add your service module to your controller module like:

```
angular.module('MainCtrl', ['MainService']).controller('MainController',
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ey3K5eF5h56dqWTji5uX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed I had done something wrong here so I barely glanced at my other files. After far too long working on this problem I realized I was just missing the controller in one of my routes.